# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'

Tags: python, python-dotenv

Facing `dotenv` not found error.

```
 % flask run
 * Tip: There are .env or .flaskenv files present. Do "pip install python-dotenv" to use them.
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 260, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/tedx/cpt/python/pythonBackend/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

My environment is setup as follow:

```
% dotenv --version
dotenv, version 0.20.0
% pip --version
pip 21.3.1 from /Users/tedx/.local/share/virtualenvs/pythonBackend-DMWtwxfH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
% python --version
Python 3.6.8
% pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2022.4.8
```

I have tried the answers to similar problem but still getting this error. Few things that I had tried are:

```
- pip uninstall python-dotenv
- pip install -U python-dotenv
```

Also `pip freeze` output shows `python-dotenv`.

```
% pip freeze                     
argcomplete==2.0.0
astroid==2.11.7
attrs==22.1.0
autograd==1.4
awscli==1.24.10
blinker==1.5
boto3==1.23.10
botocore==1.26.10
certifi==2022.6.15
cfn-flip==1.3.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
click==8.0.4
colorama==0.4.4
dataclasses==0.8
dill==0.3.4
docutils==0.16
durationpy==0.5
Flask==2.0.3
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
future==0.18.2
hjson==3.1.0
idna==3.3
importlib-metadata==4.8.3
importlib-resources==5.4.0
iniconfig==1.1.1
isort==5.10.1
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.3
jmespath==0.10.0
kappa==0.6.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.7.1
Lifetimes==0.11.3
mailjet-rest==1.3.4
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
mccabe==0.7.0
numpy==1.19.5
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.1.5
pep517==0.13.0
pip-tools==6.4.0
placebo==0.10.0
platformdirs==2.4.0
pluggy==1.0.0
py==1.11.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pylint==2.13.9
PyMySQL==1.0.2
pytest==7.0.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
*python-dotenv==0.20.0*
python-slugify==6.1.2
pytz==2022.2.1
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.27.1
rsa==4.7.2
s3transfer==0.5.2
scipy==1.5.4
sentry-sdk==1.9.5
six==1.16.0
stripe==4.1.0
text-unidecode==1.3
toml==0.10.2
tomli==1.2.3
tqdm==4.64.0
troposphere==3.1.1
typed-ast==1.5.4
typing_extensions==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.11
Werkzeug==2.0.3
wrapt==1.14.1
wsgi-request-logger==0.4.6
zappa==0.54.2
zipp==3.6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying these and re-installing dotenv fixed this issue:

```
pip uninstall dotenv
pip uninstall python-dotenv
pip install python-dotenv
```

Also you may have `dotenv` installed at the system level (outside of your virtual environment). If yes, you could try uninstalling that.

Comment: I have tried this but still getting the same error. dotenv is recognized otherwise